# how to install gcc-12 on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```sh
$ sudo apt search gcc-12
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
$ uname -a
Linux Han 5.10.81.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Mon Nov 22 18:52:15 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am using the default sources.list file, I want to install gcc-12 but I can't find it in the mirror source, what should I do!

Comment: Ubuntu, gcc-12 https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test → gcc overview http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/pool/main/g/

Comment: @KnudLarsen gcc-12 is not referenced anywhere in your links

Comment: `windows-subsystem-for-linux` : There should be a gcc-12  version for Ubuntu 22.04 .... as it is available for the default Ubuntu https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/g++-12 . ..... Ubuntu 22.04 will be released tomorrow.

Comment: As an aside, you should not need `sudo` for `apt search`

Answer (score 44):

gcc-12 is not available in ubuntu 20.04, so we need to compile it from source code, here are the steps which I borrowed from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCcUa1FPU80):

- **Step 1**: clone gcc source code and checkout gcc-12 branch

```
$ git clone https://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git gcc-source
$ cd gcc-source/
$ git branch -a
$ git checkout remotes/origin/releases/gcc-12
```

- **Step 2**: make another build dir

Note this is important as running `./configure` from within the source directory is not supported as documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC).

```
$ mkdir ../gcc-12-build
$ cd ../gcc-12-build/
$ ./../gcc-source/configure --prefix=$HOME/install/gcc-12 --enable-languages=c,c++
```

- **Step 3**: installing GCC prequisites and run configure again

The missing libraries will be shown in above `./confgiure` output, search and install them one by one.

```
$ apt-cache search MPFR
$ sudo apt-get install libmpfrc++-dev
$ apt-cache search MPC | grep dev
$ sudo apt-get install libmpc-dev
$ apt-cache search GMP | grep dev
$ sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
$ ./../gcc-source/configure --prefix=$HOME/install/gcc-12 --enable-languages=c,c++
```

An alternartive is to run the download_prerequisites script.

```
$ cd ../
$ cd gcc-source/
$ ./contrib/download_prerequisites
$ ./../gcc-source/configure --prefix=$HOME/install/gcc-12 --enable-languages=c,c++
```

- **Step 4**: compile gcc-12

```
$ make -j16
```

Still flex is missing:

```
$ sudo apt-get install flex
$ ./../gcc-source/configure --prefix=$HOME/install/gcc-12 --enable-languages=c,c++
$ make -j16
$ make install
```

Another way is to use Ubuntu 22.04 where gcc-12 is available. In Ubuntu 22.04, gcc-12 can be installed with `apt`:

```
$ sudo apt install gcc-12
```

Comment: I tried it on Kubuntu 20.04. Without download_prerequisites it complained about missing "isl" component. Also I needed to supply configure options --disable-multilib and --with-isl. Then build to succeed. However second build after flex installation failed with "Error 2" and it said I should "make distcean" first. Finally I tried install but it says target install is unknown.

Comment: Why do you do a second make after installation of flex? Why no installing flex at the beginning and then doing a single make?

Comment: @Silicomancer In my case, in the begining when running `./../gcc-source/configure`, it was not complaining missing flex, it complained until `make -j16` stage.

Comment: How add gcc-12 to alternative c and c++ compiler under linux?

Comment: @KhurshidNormuradov ```sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc ~/install/gcc-12/bin/gcc 120 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ ~/install/gcc-12/bin/g++ --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov ~/install/gcc-12/bin/gcov``` will do (assuming gcc-12 is installed in `~/install/gcc-12`). More info can be referred from https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-gcc-compiler-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Note for those of you building it on a VM: **you need quite a lot of space**. For me `gcc-source` folder is 1.9 GB and `gcc-12-build` ended up 8.2 GB. You also need sufficient swap space *(see https://askubuntu.com/a/299441 for how to create swap files if you don’t have a swap partition)* or the build might fail with signal 9.

Comment: Easiest on Ubuntu 22.04 is: ```sudo apt install gcc-12```

Answer (score 13):

You can use Homebrew to install pre-built binaries.
Follow instructions to install Homebrew at https://brew.sh/, then

`brew install gcc` for default GCC (currently 11) or `brew install gcc@12` for gcc-12.

Note that it may compile missing dependencies.

Comment: Homebrew is macOS only, right?

Comment: No, you can also use it on Linux now.

Comment: ```error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
error: 1604 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
Failed during: git fetch --force origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master```

Answer (score 3):

I would add if you are adding for 64 bit only, you'll want to add "--disable=multilib" to the end of your configure statement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

ubuntu 22.04:

```bash
sudo apt install gcc-12
```

Comment: If you want to make gcc-12 the default compiler you need to change the links in /usr/bin

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1500017/ubuntu-22-04-default-gcc-version-does-not-match-version-that-built-latest-defaul