# How do I make gcc as verbose as possible?

Tags: c, gcc

I am currently using the following flags for my gcc compiler:

```bash
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -g -c filename.c
```

But how can I make the output as verbose as possible? The error messages I am getting in C are not as nice as I am used to from more high level languages and I want to get as much information out of the gcc compiler as possible.

Comment: Compiler error messages aren't always friendly. I'd add `-Wextra` for some additional warnings, but other than that I don't know of anything you can do to make them more friendly. Do you have an example of an error you don't understand?

Comment: `-S` to generate assembly or `-g` for gdb.

Comment: `gcc --help` will literally help.

Comment: There are flags such as `-v` and `-Q`, and the whole `-d*` family, that will output lots of extra *information*, but none of it is likely to be relevant to explaining errors in your code.

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using?  More recent versions (say GCC 10, 11 or 12) give much better diagnostics than earlier versions (4.x).  If you're not using a modern version, upgrade.  You should be able to use your existing compiler to bootstrap a more modern version, but you may also find a pre-built compiler to download instead.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks - this was extremely helpful! I had difficulties understanding the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a summary of all comments I've received on this post:

1. These flags are the best you can use to make your compiler as verbose as
   possible:

   ```bash
   -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -g3
   ```

   Other flags such as `-v` and the entire `-d*` family will make the compilation process more verbose but won't enhance the error messages you are getting.
2. Check your current version with `gcc --version`. To get the newest gcc Version (i.e. gcc 12.2 since August 19, 2022) you might have to clone the gcc repository and build it yourself based on the distro (check via `lsb_release -d`) you are using.

   - Check [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70835585/how-to-install-gcc-12-on-ubuntu) out to install gcc 12.2 on Ubuntu.
   - Alternatively you could also directly get gcc-11 from apt without upgrading to the latest bleeding edge ubuntu (don't forget to use `gcc-11` instead of `gcc` afterwards to compile).