# Installing GCC 12 on Ubuntu For Windows

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, g++, clang

So I am trying to download the SerenityOS: [Link To Website](https://www.serenityos.org) and [Github](https://www.github.com/SerenityOS/serenity).

But I am getting the following error:

```
die: Please make sure that GCC version 12, Clang version 13 or higher is installed.
```

When I enter the following command:

```
Meta/serenity.sh rebuild-toolchain
```

This command builds the serenity os.

This is **happening** in the **Ubuntu for Windows** app/console.

I have tried to find ways to install GCC 12 on Ubuntu for Windows but couldn't find anything.

I have also tried looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70835585/how-to-install-gcc-12-on-ubuntu) but I couldn't get use those steps because when I enter the command:

```
git clone https://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git gcc-source
```

I get the following error:

```
Cloning into 'gcc-source'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
```

I currently have `GCC 9.4.0` but I would like it to be GCC 12 or later. I also have `g++ 9.4.0`.

**Question:**

*So how would I get GCC 12 and Clang 13 on Ubuntu for Windows to allow me to use the `Meta/serenity.sh rebuild-toolchain`?*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70835585/how-to-install-gcc-12-on-ubuntu it's installing on my WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

Please use a newer Ubuntu version (assuming you run on a virtualized environment - this should be easy). SerenityOS is a very fast paced product - that means using an operating system from 4-2 years ago will not be easy.